# Javascript error reference container not defined

Tags: javascript

I've had this error for quite sometime now and I am not sure how to fix it. Can someone point me in the right direction?

var xxx, yyy;

```
        if (e.offsetY == null) {
            var offset = $(container).offset();

            //this.clickX = e.pageX - offset.left;
           // this.clickY = e.pageY - offset.top; FIX

            xxx = (e.pageX - offset.left) - this.chart.plotLeft;
            yyy = (e.pageY - offset.top) - this.chart.plotTop - 50;
        }
        else {
            xxx = e.offsetX - this.chart.plotLeft;
            yyy = e.offsetY - this.chart.plotTop;
        }
        e.offsetY = e.offsetY ? e.offsetY : e.pageX - $(container).offset().top;

        if (!this.chart.isInsidePlot(xxx, yyy)) {

            console.log("{FN LINE} drag -> return on [IF !chart.isInsidePlot]")

            return;
        }
```

Comment: Well, the error is telling you what the problem is. Where is `container` declared?

Comment: Did you mean $("#container").offset() maybe...you must use the id of the container with prefix '#' if it's an id (and '.' if it's a class).

Comment: I believe you are right I am going to try that I did see that.